# SQL Database script migration

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

=> We have two identical SQL database **DB1** and **DB2** having same schema and data.
e.g. I have a Language table in **DB1** and **DB2** contains same data as shown in figure

Language table of **DB1**

[image]

Language table of **DB2**

[image]

both tables looks identical in schema and data

Now, i have inserted a record in **DB1**

[image]

and update a existing record in **DB2**

[image]

From here, Language table of **DB1** and **DB2** is no more identical

Now, I have generate insert script for Language table of **DB1**

[image]

Now, I want to run this script in **DB2**

If I  run this script in **DB2**,

[image]

Till now everything is ok.
But I don't want records of Language table of **DB2** in this manner, due to my different requirement 
Now the actual question begins.

I want this script should take care the updated record of Language Table in  **DB2**. I mean to say It should check updated record of Language Table in **DB2** i.e. updated record should remain intact.
It means after running script Language Table of  **DB2** should be
[image]

How should we do that or what changes should we make in our script that would take care of these changes

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
Given this setup
drop table languages
CREATE TABLE LANGUAGES
(TITLE CHAR(5),DESCRIPTION CHAR(20), ID INT)

INSERT INTO LANGUAGES
(TITLE ,DESCRIPTION, ID) 
VALUES 
('UK','uNITED kINGDOM',1),
('US','uNITED STATES',2),
('N','nORWAY',3),
('fi','Finland',4)

This update statement works
*/

update languages
set title = 'nb-NV' where id = 3
```

Comment: thats absolutely right , but I want to track this automatically. I dont know what row is updated in DB2 table assume DB2 as a client side database. and I have noo clue what is added their in which data record.    I need to keep those changes automatically

Answer (score 0):

If you ok with manual merging database, you should take a look on this tools:

- [Open DBDiff](http://opendbiff.codeplex.com/) - free
- [Red Gate](http://www.red-gate.com/) - not free, expensive ;)
- if you user Microsoft Visual 2015 you can use built in data comparison functionality